Is there a beamer option to change section of a given frame
Given multiple frames in a beamer presentation. I want to shift some of the frames to the end/backup section of the presentation. Is there an option that can help achieve this?
The following is an example of what I am trying to achieve.
\begin{frame}
The Plot at Station 1
\end{frame}

% This frame should be in the backup since I want to include it but not present it unless need be.
% So looking for an option like \setbeameroption{sendtoBackup}. 
% Instead of manually moving the code to Backup.

\begin{frame}
The Plot at Station 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
The Plot at Station 3
\end{frame}




Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You could use the beamersubframe package:
\documentclass{beamer}
 
\usepackage[append]{beamersubframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
The Plot at Station 1
\end{frame}

% This frame should be in the backup since I want to include it but not present it unless need be.
% So looking for an option like \setbeameroption{sendtoBackup}. 
% Instead of manually moving the code to Backup.

\begin{subframe}
The Plot at Station 2
\end{subframe}

\begin{frame}
The Plot at Station 3
\end{frame}


\appendix

\appendsubframes

\end{document}

